# How to stop php 'for loop' from creating multiple table headers

Tags: php, html

I am creating a table that fetches data from an SQL database using a PDO method. The data loads fine but the issue I'm having is that the 'for loop' I'm using is multiplying a  (table header) after every  (table row).

I am wondering what a possible solution the the issue could be.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Here is the code:

```
<?php

for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){

?>

    <table id="eventstable">
      <tr>
        <th>Event ID</th>
        <th>Event Name</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Date</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['event_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['event_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['event_location']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['event_date']; ?></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

        <?php }


 ?>
```

Up at the very top is the connection file that creates a connection to my local database and a statement that brings in the information I want to display from the database like so:

```
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM events");
$result->execute();
```

Comment: Hi, if you want to output the header once, you need to place it before the loop. :)

Comment: When I do that, the loop only displays one row of data and the rest shows up un-formatted and without any styling...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few possible solutions are 
i) Put the header part and the table opening and closing tag outside the for loop. This will give you an empty table with headers if there is no data. 
ii) Put an if condition and print headers only when i = 0, and put table tags outside the loop. This will give you an empty table with nothing if there is no data.

Edit: Method II (since you are learning)

```
<table id="eventstable">

<?php

for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){

if($i == 0){
?>


      <tr>
        <th>Event ID</th>
        <th>Event Name</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Date</th>
      </tr>


      <?php  }//if statment ends here ?>
   <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['event_id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['event_name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['event_location']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['event_date']; ?></td>
  </tr>


        <?php }


 ?>
```

I would also suggest since you are learning, use better ways than for loop. Look at the php PDO manuals and see the use of while or foreach. It will help more.

Comment: I did the first solution that you gave me and it worked perfectly! It is kind of a  strange way to fix it but it got the job done. Thanks!

Comment: Can you give me an example of how your second solution would work? I'm really new to php so I'm curious as to how you would write it out, thanks!

Comment: Added. If this has answered your question, you can accept the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Accepted! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
    <table id="eventstable">
      <tr>
        <th>Event ID</th>
        <th>Event Name</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Date</th>
      </tr>
<?php

foreach($result->fetch() as $row){

?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['event_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['event_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['event_location']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['event_date']; ?></td>
      </tr>
<?php }


 ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: it would be a good idea to suggest him to use foreach instead of for

Answer (score 0):

Put in loop only, what should be looped, everything else should be outside of loop.

For example, your code could look like this

```
        <table id="eventstable">
          <tr>
            <th>Event ID</th>
            <th>Event Name</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Date</th>
          </tr>
<?php        
    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){        
    ?>    
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['event_id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['event_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['event_location']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['event_date']; ?></td>
          </tr>        
 <?php 
     }
     ?>
        </table>
```

Comment: I attempted it this way but it just didn't seem to work. With this solution only the first table row was being styled and formatted while the others were just plain un-formatted data...

Comment: Maybe you've closed table too fast (inside loop)? This is only reason that i can think of